# How service worker works?

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, service-worker-events

I am newbie to progressive web apps. I have gone through [**this**](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/build-a-realtime-pwa-with-react-99e7b0fd3270) amazing tutorial and setup for my react PWA(progressive web) app.

Now this is my **serviceworker.js** file

```
const isLocalhost = Boolean(
  window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ||
    window.location.hostname === '[::1]' ||
    window.location.hostname.match(
      /^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/
    )
);

export default function register() {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location);
    if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
      return;
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;

      if (isLocalhost) {
        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl);
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
        });
      } else {
        registerValidSW(swUrl);
      }
    });
  }
}

function registerValidSW(swUrl) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then(registration => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              console.log('New content is available; please refresh.');
            } else {
              console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');
            }
          }
        };
      };
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    });
}

function checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl) {
  fetch(swUrl)
    .then(response => {
      if (
        response.status === 404 ||
        response.headers.get('content-type').indexOf('javascript') === -1
      ) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
          registration.unregister().then(() => {
            window.location.reload();
          });
        });
      } else {
        registerValidSW(swUrl);
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log(
        'No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.'
      );
    });
}

export function unregister() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
      registration.unregister();
    });
  }
}
```

But could not able to understand how it works? Can anyone please help what register, unregister and other function do here?

Please help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-service-worker):

> A **service worker** is a type of **web worker**. It's essentially a
>   JavaScript file that runs separately from the main browser thread,
>   intercepting network requests, caching or retrieving resources from
>   the cache, and delivering push messages.

From your sample code above, you are using react framework to build PWA with `create-react-app`. It will eliminates all of that by allowing developers to build React apps with little or no build configuration.

To [Build a realtime PWA with React](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/build-a-realtime-pwa-with-react-99e7b0fd3270):

> The **service worker code** basically registers a service worker for
>   the React app.  We first check if the app is being served from localhost via the `isLocalhost` const value that will either return a truthy or falsy value. The `register()` function helps to register the
>   service worker to the React app only if its in a production mode and
>   if the browser supports Service workers.

The `registerValidSW()` function that will register the valid service worker and responsible for the state if it is installed.
The `checkValidServiceWorker()` will check if service worker can be found. This will ensure service worker exists, and that we really are getting a JS file.

> The `unregister()` function
>   helps to unregister the service worker.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. No one replies in this forum